# Making React + MUI component mobile responsive - Need assistance to achieve it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, material-ui

I have a React component created using Material-UI (MUI) that I'm trying to make mobile responsive. Currently, it looks like this:

[image: Now, it looks like this]

But I want it to look like this

[image: It should look like this]

Here's the relevant code for the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Box, Paper, useMediaQuery, useTheme, Typography, Grid, Container, Accordion, AccordionSummary, AccordionDetails, Rating,
} from '@mui/material';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import FormGroup from '@mui/material/FormGroup';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import LocationOnIcon from './SVGiCON';


export const CarInfo: React.FC = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'));

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    gilad: false,
    jason: false,
    antoine: false,
  });

  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);
  const [ratings, setRatings] = React.useState<number[]>([4, 5, 3, 4.5]);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.checked,
    });
  };

  const handleExpandToggle = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };

  const { gilad, jason, antoine } = state;
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<number | null>(2);


  return (
    <Container>
      <Box
        display="flex"
        flexDirection="column"
        alignItems="center"
        justifyContent="center"
        height="150vh"
      >
        <Paper
          elevation={3}
          sx={{
            p: 3,
            borderRadius: 2,
            textAlign: 'center',
            maxWidth: isMobile ? '100%' : 'xl',
            width: '1100px',
            height: '1000px',
            backgroundColor: 'grey !important',
          }}
        >
          {/* Car Title */}
          <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom color={'white'}>
            Car Title
          </Typography>

          <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
            <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={6} xl={6}>
              {/* Add your car details here */}
              <Typography variant="body1" align="left">
                Собственик{' '}
                <Link to="/home" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', marginLeft: '10px' }}>
                  <span style={{
                    color: 'black', backgroundColor: 'green', borderRadius: '50px', padding: '10px',
                  }}>
                    Александър Иванов
                  </span>
                </Link>
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '40px', marginTop: '20px', marginBottom: '20px' }}>
                <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '10px', width: '15px', height: '15px' }} />
                Костинброд, София-област
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '40px' }}>
                Детайли за колата:
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '40px' }}>
                <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '10px', width: '15px', height: '15px' }} />
                Бензин
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '40px' }}>
                <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '10px', width: '15px', height: '15px' }} />
                Черен
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '40px' }}>
                <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '10px', width: '15px', height: '15px' }} />
                2022 г.
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '40px' }}>
                <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '10px', width: '15px', height: '15px' }} />
                90 000 км
              </Typography>

              <FormGroup style={{ marginLeft: '40px', marginTop: '11px' }}>
                <FormControlLabel
                  style={{ marginBottom: '-10px', color: "black" }}
                  control={
                    <Checkbox
                      checked={gilad}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      name="gilad"
                      size='small'
                      style={{ color: 'black' }} />
                  }
                  label="Реален пробег"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                  style={{ color: "black" }}
                  control={
                    <Checkbox checked={jason}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      name="jason"
                      size='small'
                      style={{ color: 'black' }} />
                  }
                  label="Първи собственик"
                />
              </FormGroup>

            </Grid>


            {/* Car Image (on the right for larger screens) */}
            <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={6} xl={6}>
              {/* Add your image component here */}
              <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="Car" style={{ width: '482px', height: '279px', marginRight: '50px' }} />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>

          <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '40px', marginTop: '40px' }}>
            Лиценз
          </Typography>

          <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="flex-start" justifyContent="center">
            <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
              <Box
                sx={{
                  position: 'relative',
                  width: '100%',
                  paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9 aspect ratio (modify as needed)
                  overflow: 'hidden',
                }}
              >
                {/* Add your car details here */}
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/533669/pexels-photo-533669.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
                  alt="Car"
                  // style={{
                  // width: '454px', height: '331px', marginLeft: '40px', marginTop: '20px',
                // }} />
                  style={{
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: 20,
                    borderRadius: 0,
                    left: 40,
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    objectFit: 'cover', // or 'contain' depending on your preference
                  }} />
              </Box>
            </Grid>

            {/* Car Image (on the right for larger screens) */}
            <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={6} xl={6} container style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
              {/* Add your image component here */}
              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start', marginTop: '20px' }}>
                Линк към документа{' '}
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start', marginTop: '20px', wordBreak: 'break-all' }}>
                <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_certificate#/media/File:1917_auto_registration_license.jpg" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_certificate#/media/File:1917_auto_registration_license.jpg
                </a>
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={6} xl={6}>
            {/* ... (Existing code) ... */}

            {/* Expandable Rating Section */}
            <Accordion expanded={expanded}
              onChange={handleExpandToggle}
              style={{
              marginTop: '20px', width: '400px', textAlign: 'left', marginLeft: '40px', backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            }}>
              <AccordionSummary
                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
                id="panel1bh-header"
            >
                <Typography variant="body1">Рейтинг</Typography>
              </AccordionSummary>
              <AccordionDetails>
                <div>
                  <Rating name="read-only" value={value} readOnly size="large" />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <Rating name="read-only" value={value} readOnly size="large" />
                </div>
              </AccordionDetails>
            </Accordion>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={6} xl={6}>
            {/* ... (Existing code) ... */}

            {/* Expandable Rating Section */}
            <Accordion expanded={expanded}
              onChange={handleExpandToggle}
              style={{
              marginTop: '20px', width: '400px', textAlign: 'left', marginLeft: '40px', backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            }}>
              <AccordionSummary
                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
                id="panel1bh-header"
            >
                <Typography variant="body1">Коментари</Typography>
              </AccordionSummary>
              <AccordionDetails>
                <div>
                  <Rating name="read-only" value={value} readOnly size="large" />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <Rating name="read-only" value={value} readOnly size="large" />
                </div>
              </AccordionDetails>
            </Accordion>
          </Grid>
        </Paper>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
};
export default CarInfo;
```

I've tried a lot of different things, but I'm facing challenges achieving the desired mobile responsiveness. Can someone provide guidance on how to structure the styles or any MUI-specific considerations to achieve the desired mobile layout?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This is a question with a broad scope, so this wouldn't be well served in stackoverflow I think. Did you try with chatgpt? https://chat.openai.com/share/13a1be59-c2d1-462e-903b-b96022ddf29e

Comment: Yes, I tried in the last 2 days to make it with ChatGPT, but it didn't helped me at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things that you can work on:

### Image

I can see that you're using the `img` tag from html with width and height in pixels. You can give them in vh or vw or in percentage to make them responsive.

### Paper component

```js
<Paper
  elevation={3}
  sx={{
    p: 3,
    borderRadius: 2,
    textAlign: 'center',
    maxWidth: isMobile ? '100%' : 'xl',
    width: '1100px',
    height: '1000px',
    backgroundColor: 'grey !important',
  }}
>
```

In this block of code you are giving the width and height of you paper component which will restrict the responsiveness of your component. You can also use percentage or you can give it's parent a max-width to make this responsive.

Also the positioning and structuring is not fixed. You can checkout some blogs or articles to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! 

Btw, any other help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can ask any doubt and I will try my best to help you 

Comment: I didn't manage to achieve it, can you help me?

Comment: Can you share the repo link. I will try to make it

Comment: Wow! This is amazing!

Yes, of course! 

It is a private repo, how do you want to share it to you?

Will wait for your reply!